# Как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на копку "BUY" ссылка перешла сразу на адрес находившийся между `<redirect> </redirect>`

Tags: php, xml, redirect

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать кнопку на ссылку находившийся между `<redirect> </redirect>` с помощью PHP. Учитывая то что адрес находившийся между `<redirect> </redirect>` каждый раз меняется.

```
<response>
<redirect>
https://pay.millikart.az/epayment/ClientHandler?trans_id=4l4Pp30T%2F7oKixnMqUGivODtm28%3D
</redirect>
<code>0</code>
<description>OK</description>
</response>
```

Умудрился как то так но ничего не работает.

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        return $xml->redirect;
```

этот код находится в файле под названиям "millikart.php"

```
<?php


class Millikart {
    private $mid            = "wayyat";
    private $secretkey      = "UR6L2STAD8A0OKD6G2MXKA62BM59QKSV";
    private $status         = "1"; // Əgər production level-ə keçmisinizsə 0 əvəzinə 1 yazın
    private $currency       = "944"; //AZN
    private $language       = "az";
    private $test_url       = "http://test.millikart.az:8513";
    private $pro_url        = "https://pay.millikart.az";
    public  $description;
    public  $amount;
    public  $reference;
    public function __construct($amount, $reference, $description){
        $this->amount = $amount*100;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->reference = $reference;
    }

    private function signature() {

        $data = strlen($this->mid);
        $data .= $this->mid;
        $data .= strlen($this->amount);
        $data .= $this->amount;
        $data .= strlen($this->currency);
        $data .= $this->currency;
        if(!empty($this->description)) {
            $data .= strlen($this->description);
            $data .= $this->description;
        }
        else{
            $data .= "0";
        }

        $data .= strlen($this->reference);  
        $data .= $this->reference;  
        $data .= strlen($this->language);
        $data .= $this->language;   
        $data .= $this->secretkey;
        $data = md5($data);
        $data = strtoupper($data);
        return $data;
    }
    public function getURL(){
        $data_url ="/gateway/payment/register?mid=".$this->mid."&amount=".$this->amount."&currency=".$this->currency."&description=".$this->description."&reference=".$this->reference."&language=".$this->language."&signature=".$this->signature();
        if($this->status == "0") {
            $url = $this->test_url.$data_url;
        }
        else {
            $url = $this->pro_url.$data_url;
        }
        $xml = file_get_contents($url);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        //return $xml->redirect;
        return $url;


    }
}
```

А на другом файле "pay.php"

```
<?php
ob_start();
$___notjson=1;
require_once("millikart.php");
$referrence = rand(1000000000,9999999999).time();
$amount = "1";
$description = "BakuDubaimmk";

$payment = new Millikart($amount,$referrence,$description);
$response = $payment->getURL();
echo "<a href=".$response.">BUY</a>";

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

И как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на копку "BUY" ссылка перешла сразу на адрес находившийся между `<redirect> </redirect>`

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал код

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->redirect;
```

Все работает. Конечно переменная $url должна содержать корректное имя файла или урл, по которому надо скачать. Ну и кончено, если доступ к файлу идет по урл - PHP должен иметь права на скачивание файлов из сети.

Если не работает - включай вывод ошибок.